# Which object is Thing.this in an inner class

Tags: java

I have a simple class:

```
Public class Store {
   Product product = new Product();

   public class Product{
      Store getStore(){
         //What does this return statement mean?
         return Store.this;
      }
   }
}
```

I am wondering whether the `Store.this;` in the return statement means the instance of `Store` which hosts the `product`?

Comment: `"I am wondering whether the Store.this; in the return statement means the instance of Store which hosts the product?"`: Yes it does. That's what `Store.this` means.

Comment: Com'on, can't you figure out with some debug?

Comment: RC. come on, teach me ;)

Comment: you are returning the outsider object..

Comment: This question shows a clear lack of research before posting. StackOverflow is not a replacement for your compiler, IDE, or Google.

Comment: Marko, I see. Please calm down, don't criticize me like this, if I know how to prove my guessing I won't post it. But I will try to think carefully before posting next time. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Mellon I have stated what I take as the opinion of the StackOverflow community on your question. There are no emotions, negative or otherwise, involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public class OuterClass{    
   public class InnerClass{
         //OuterClass.this is used to refer the current reference of outer class
         //this referes to the current instance of innner (self) class
   }
}
```

Comment: I prefer your answer, straight forward :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. See [JLS 15.8.4: Qualified this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4):

> Any lexically enclosing instance (§8.1.3) can be referred to by
>   explicitly qualifying the keyword this.
>
> Let C be the class denoted by ClassName. Let n be an integer such that
>   C is the n'th lexically enclosing class of the class in which the
>   qualified this expression appears.
>
> The value of an expression of the form ClassName.this is the n'th
>   lexically enclosing instance of this.

In this case, the lexical enclosing instance is the `Store` instance.

Comment: Thanks! Clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need an instance of the outer class (in this case, `Store`) to create an instance of the inner class (in this case, `Product`). So, in the inner class you can use `OuterClass.this` to mark the difference between the `this` instance returned by the inner class.